# AOP using AspectJ not working in spring?

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-annotations

My Aspect class will be ,

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Component
@Aspect
public class AspectClass {

    @Before("execution(* com.pointel.aop.test1.AopTest.beforeAspect())")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        System.out.println("Before running the beforeAspect() in the AopTest.java class!");
        System.out.println("Hijacked Method name : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        System.out.println("************************");
    }

}
```

My other java Class

```
public class AopTest {

    public void beforeAspect() {
        System.out.println("This is beforeAspect() !");
    }
}
```

My Main Class is

```
public class MainMethod {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext/applicationContext.xml");
        AopTest test = (AopTest)context.getBean("bean1");
        test.beforeAspect();
    }
}
```

My applicationContext.xml is ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

    <bean id="bean1" class="com.pointel.aop.test1.AopTest" />

</beans>
```

In this the `@Before("execution(* com.pointel.aop.test1.AopTest.beforeAspect())")` in the `AspectClass` will not be executed before the `beforeAspect()` in the `AopTest` , when running Main method.

Good answers are definitely appreciated.

Comment: Dont make your Configuration class the same as your Aspect class. Also, you need to `@ComponentScan` the package your Aspect is in.

Comment: I deleted the `@Configuration` and included the `@ComponentScan` but still not working.

Comment: Take a look below, there are a few things you were missing.

Answer (score 4):

First of all if you're going to use an annotation based configuration, use `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` instead of `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`. And get rid of the `applicationContext.xml` file and simply add a `@Bean` method in your configuration class. Something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "your.aspect.package")
public class AspectConfig {
    @Bean 
    public AopTest aopTest() {
        return new AopTest();
    }
}
```

In your main

```
public class MainMethod {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContextcontext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AspectConfig.class);
        // don't forget to refresh
        context.refresh();
        AopTest test = (AopTest)context.getBean("aopTest");
        test.beforeAspect();
    }
}
```

In `AspectClass` you should have `@Component`, `@Aspect`, and your method should have the advice or pointcut annotation like `@Before`. It needs to be a `@Component`, so that Spring knows to scan it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...Am I want to delete the four annotations in the `AspectClass` ?

Comment: In `AspectClass` you should have `@Component`, `@Aspect`, and your method should have the advice or pointcut annotation like `@Before`. It needs to be a `@Component`, so that Spring knows to scan it. Updated my answer

Comment: What is the need for `context.refresh();` ? Got the solution without the '`context.refresh();`'.

Comment: You can change configurations at runtime, (I think). `refresh()` basically drops all beans and recreates for the new configuration.

Comment: `AopTest` Constructor is invoked twice and do you know why ?

Comment: Can you update your original question with your new classes? I'll take a look. I can't tell like this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27023/discussion-between-anand-and-sotirios-delimanolis)

Answer (score 1):

Here some code need to add in xml to use annotations-
1.for @component annotation.

```
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
```

2.after that use component scan to get all annotated bean class which use @component annotation,and use aop autoproxy-

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="mypackage"></context:component-scan>
 <aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
```

for examples visit-[www.technicaltoday.com/p/spring.html](http://www.technicaltoday.com/p/spring.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer...I don't need to do it with `xml` and purely looking for annotation based `AspectJ`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the point cut definition in your aspect class.

For example;

```
@Pointcut("execution(* *.advice(..))")  
public void logBefore(){}  

@Before("logBefore()")  
public void beforeAdvicing(){  
System.out.println("Listen Up!!!!");  
}
```

You first have to defin the point to weave your aspect to. You do this by using Point cuts.It is the point cut name you give within your @Before annotation. Have a look at my blog post for more information @ http://dinukaroshan.blogspot.com/2010/06/aop-with-spring.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your `AspectClass` in the beans configuration. You should also declare it as a Bean.